# CSRF : How to set cookie named XSRF-TOKEN in JAX-RS from backend to use with AngularJS in frontend

Tags: angularjs, rest, csrf

My application uses AngularJS in the front end and Java RESTful web services at the back end. We are trying to use XSRF-TOKEN to prevent cross site request forgery.

On the front end, I have the angular-cookies.js added, and included the ngCookies dependency in my 'module'.

```
angular.module('myapp.list', ['ngCookies'])
 .controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function CoiListCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
   //some functions
  })
.run(['$http', '$cookies', function($http, $cookies) {
//check if the header X-XSRF-TOKEN is already set by AngularJS
console.log($http.defaults.headers.post['X-XSRF-TOKEN']);
    debugger;
}]);
```

On the front end I am unable to see the cookie that I have created on the back end in both the below ways:

## 1

Using the `HttpServletResponse` object, but this way I'm unsure as to how this is sent back to the UI as we are not using anything like `httpResponse.sendRedirect(url);`

```
@Context
HttpServletResponse httpResponse;
httpResponse.addCookie(new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", String.valueOf(Math.random()));
```

## 2

Adding the cookies to the `ResponseBuilder` as we return response using the `responseBuilder.build()` method in a typical JAX-RS service

```
ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.temporaryRedirect(new URI(redirectUrl));
NewCookie abc = new NewCookie("XSRF-TOKEN", String.valueOf(Math.random()));
responseBuilder.cookie(abc);
return responseBuilder.build();
```

Could someone please help me create valid cookies and use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own implementation of ServletFilter, where you will check presence of CRSF header and CSRF cookie and check if they will match each other.
Code example:

```
boolean isRequestContainsValidCsrfToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String authCookie = Arrays.stream(request.getCookies())
                .filter(cookie -> cookie.getName().equals(COOKIE_NAME))
                .findFirst()
                .map(Cookie::getValue)
                .orElse(null);
        String authHeader = request.getHeader(X_CSRF_TOKEN);
        

        return authCookie != null && authCookie.equals(authHeader);
    }
```